# Powershell script to double check Active Directory users logged in over 30 days ago

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a script to disable user accounts that have been inactive for the past 30 days. I have a script to go through all the DCs in our environment to pull user information if they last logged in 30-days ago. However, this does not account for logs from these same users within the last 30 days.

Below is a script I have to double check, but it isn't pulling correct information:

```
$activeusers = @()
foreach($row in $dc) {
foreach($user in $AllUsers) {
$hostname = $row.hostname
$name = $user.Name
$currentuser = @(Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $True -and lastLogonTimestamp -gt $time } -Server $hostname -Properties Name, SamAccountName, EmailAddress, Department, Description, LastLogonTimestamp, DistinguishedName | 
Select Name, SamAccountName, EmailAddress, Department, Description, DistinguishedName,@{n='lastLogonTimestamp';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} | 
Where-Object { ($_.Name -match $name -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*User*" -or $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Contractor*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Service*"  -and $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Extended*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Disabled*") } ) 
$activeusers += $currentuser
} }
```

Even though I have the $_.Name -match $name line in the Where-Object statement, the script pulls users outside of the original list and doesn't contain a single user from the first list.

I have also tried changing the comparable variable to the EmailAddress and the SamAccountName, as well as putting the comparable variable in the -Filter line.